# Why do some Excel users use SUM() when it is not needed?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

It's perfectly valid syntax to write

```
=A1/A2
```

as well as quick to read and write (I'm assuming for the sake of argument that A1 and A2 are numbers, where A2 is non-zero).

What I don't understand is when some users write things like

```
=SUM(A1/A2).
```

**Why do some users do this?**  I.e., is there any benefit to writing formulae in this way? Is it a legacy of older syntax?

Answer (score 2):

I personally tend to write =SUM before any math operators to easily differentiate between those cells or parts of a formula which are simple math and those which are more complex math or logic. Simple personal preference, but I find it helps me keep track of things.

Answer (score 1):

They might prefer to type it out for whatever reason. It's also possible that this is how they were taught and so they do it by habit.

Comment: There is some extra feeling of security when coding against a method rather than an adhoc expression, as the parameters can be validated as you type.

Answer (score 1):

I do my formulas as =Sum(A1:A2) because sometimes I will insert rows and it the formula will adjust itself to =sum(A1:A3). Where if I do it as =A1+A2 then I have to go adjust.